# Razzing vs teasing

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, synonyms

What's the difference between "razzing" and "teasing" stylistically and in terms of the meaning? Urban Dictionary says "razzing" is a simple term for "flirting" but I can't find this definition elsewhere on the internet. Also some sources define "razzing" as "teasing in an unkind way". 
Or is "razzing" just simply an American English synonym of teasing?

Comment: I don't know about the meaning, but _teasing_ is a standard English word and  _razzing_ isn't.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks!